# Rearranging coordinate equation

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

I am looking to rearrange the following equation, given that I already know the distance and one set of coordinates (I need to find the coordinates of the second point basically)

$$d = \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2}.$$

I know $d$ and I know $x_1$ and $y_1$ (or $x_2$ and $y_2$)

EDIT - Seeing as this simply gives me a circle, I'll expand the criteria:

I have a rectangle. I know its angle of rotation (it may also not be rotated, its optional), the height and width, and the coordinates of one point, say, the top left. Is it now possible to figure out where the other points lie and ultimately, the centre of the rectangle?

Answer (score 1):

There is an infinite number of points a fixed number away from a given point, and they describe a circle. To see that, square your equation to get
$$
(x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2 = d^2
$$
and notice that this is exactly the equation of the circle centered at $(x_1,y_1)$ with radius $d$...

Comment: Does it help that I know the other point is part of a rectangle? So, given the height and width of the sides, plus the single point coordinates, can I find the other points? I'd also know the angle of either the "left" or "right" sides of the rectangle

Comment: @PaulCanning i did not understand, but if you impose additional conditions, it may be enough to determine your point exactly.